# Upload a static JSON file to a virtual server (VPS)

Tags: json

How can I upload a static JSON file to a virtual server on Windows? (Windows Server 2012 R2). When that is done I need to transport that file to the Android client.

Comment: Please post some code that you already have. [Check this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Unfortunately I have just the code in Xamarin.Android to load the JSON from the Asset. I have purchased VPS of OVH. And I have no idea how to begin to upload my JSON file in this virtual server.